# C++ instantiate class explicitly with default template values, except the second-last value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

This could be a really simple question.

I have the following (templated) class definition.

```cpp
template <
    /// Element type for A matrix operand
    typename ElementA_,
    /// Layout type for A matrix operand
    typename LayoutA_,
    /// Element type for B matrix operand
    typename ElementB_,
    /// Layout type for B matrix operand
    typename LayoutB_,
    /// Element type for C and D matrix operands
    typename ElementC_,
    /// Layout type for C and D matrix operands
    typename LayoutC_,
    /// Element type for internal accumulation
    typename ElementAccumulator_ = ElementC_,
    /// Operator class tag
    typename OperatorClass_ = arch::OpClassSimt,
    /// Tag indicating architecture to tune for
    typename ArchTag_ = arch::Sm70,
    //... a lot more typename´s with default values...,
    typename Operator_ = typename DefaultGemmConfiguration<
        OperatorClass_, ArchTag_, ElementA_, ElementB_, ElementC_,
        ElementAccumulator_>::Operator,
    /// Whether Beta is zero or not
    bool IsBetaZero = false>
class Gemm {
 public:
...
```

I would like to instantiate that class with all it´s default template types, except for one, the second-last one in the template list actually. How to do this? My guess would be something like this:

```cpp
using CutlassGemm = cutlass::gemm::device::Gemm<float,        // Data-type of A matrix
                                                  ColumnMajor,  // Layout of A matrix
                                                  float,        // Data-type of B matrix
                                                  ColumnMajor,  // Layout of B matrix
                                                  float,        // Data-type of C matrix
                                                  ColumnMajor,
                                                  default,
                                                  default,
                                                  // a lot more default values
                                                  default,
                                                  arch::MinimumAddOp,// <---- this one should NOT be the default
                                                  default>; // Layout of C matrix

  // Define a CUTLASS GEMM type
  CutlassGemm gemm_operator;
```

Comment: What happens when you try to do this? Is it a compiler error? Does it not work somehow? And also, you should be able to make a much simpler example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @cigen `default` is a reserved word which is not allowed as a template argument.

Comment: You may want to look e.g. [here](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/12/02/named-arguments/)

Comment: Usually, you order the argument so that those with default values are at the end... You can also define a templated alias if you often need that some specific selection of parameters to be specified. Or simply derive classes for those cases. Not sure that you are using the right approach if you have that much parameters.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I am using a library and I have to use C++11